# np.genfromtxt multiple delimiters?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, typeerror, genfromtxt

My file looks like this:

```
1497484825;34425;-4,28,-14;-4,28,-14;-4,28,-14;-4,28,-14;-4,28,-14;-4,28,-14
1497484837;34476;-4,28,-14;-4,28,-14;-4,28,-14;-4,28,-14;-4,28,-14;-4,28,-14
```

I want to import it into numpy array using np.genfromtxt. The biggest problem is that it has ';' and ',' as delimiters.
My try:

```
import numpy as np
import io

s = io.StringIO(open('2e70dfa1.csv').read().replace(';',','))

data = np.genfromtxt(s,dtype=int,delimiter=',')
```

I get error:

> TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

How to solve it? I'm also open to completely new (better) ideas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html):

> **Parameters**:
>   *fname* : file, str, pathlib.Path, list of str, generator
>   File, filename, list, or generator to read. If the filename extension
>   is gz or bz2, the file is first decompressed. Note that generators
>   must return byte strings in Python 3k. The strings in a list or
>   produced by a generator are treated as lines.

Probably easier and more efficient to give it a generator, just bearing in mind it must yield byte-strings:

```
>>> with open('2e70dfa1.csv', 'rb') as f:
...     clean_lines = (line.replace(b';',b',') for line in f)
...     data = np.genfromtxt(clean_lines, dtype=int, delimiter=',')
...
>>> data
array([[1497484825,      34425,         -4,         28,        -14,
                -4,         28,        -14,         -4,         28,
               -14,         -4,         28,        -14,         -4,
                28,        -14,         -4,         28,        -14],
       [1497484837,      34476,         -4,         28,        -14,
                -4,         28,        -14,         -4,         28,
               -14,         -4,         28,        -14,         -4,
                28,        -14,         -4,         28,        -14]])
```

Answer (score 2):

[Per the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) for numpy.genfromtxt:

> Note that generators must return byte strings in Python 3k.

So instead of creating an `StringIO` object, create a [`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o):

```
import numpy as np 
import io

s = io.BytesIO(open('2e70dfa1.csv', 'rb').read().replace(b';',b','))
data = np.genfromtxt(s,dtype=int,delimiter=',')
```

yields

```
array([[1497484825,      34425,         -4,         28,        -14,
                -4,         28,        -14,         -4,         28,
               -14,         -4,         28,        -14,         -4,
                28,        -14,         -4,         28,        -14],
       [1497484837,      34476,         -4,         28,        -14,
                -4,         28,        -14,         -4,         28,
               -14,         -4,         28,        -14,         -4,
                28,        -14,         -4,         28,        -14]])
```

---

Note that if you have [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) installed, you could use `pd.read_table` which would allow you to specify a regex pattern as a delimiter:

```
import pandas as pd     
df = pd.read_table('2e70dfa1.csv', sep=';|,', engine='python', header=None)
print(df)
```

yields

```
           0      1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
0  1497484825  34425  -4  28 -14  -4  28 -14  -4  28 -14  -4  28 -14  -4  28 -14  -4  28 -14
1  1497484837  34476  -4  28 -14  -4  28 -14  -4  28 -14  -4  28 -14  -4  28 -14  -4  28 -14
```

`pd.read_table` returns a DataFrame. If you need a NumPy array, you could access it through its `values` attribute:

```
In [24]: df.values
Out[24]: 
array([[1497484825,      34425,         -4,         28,        -14,
                -4,         28,        -14,         -4,         28,
               -14,         -4,         28,        -14,         -4,
                28,        -14,         -4,         28,        -14],
       [1497484837,      34476,         -4,         28,        -14,
                -4,         28,        -14,         -4,         28,
               -14,         -4,         28,        -14,         -4,
                28,        -14,         -4,         28,        -14]])
```